# 型ヒントで`Dict[str, Any]`をエイリアスにする場合、どんな名前が良いでしょうか？

Tags: python

## 背景

WebAPIのPythonクライアントライブラリを作成しています。
メソッドは以下のような形で、`Dict[str, Any]`を何個も書いています。

```py
def get_hoge(self, project_id: str,
                       header_params: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
                       query_params: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    pass
```

`Dict[str, Any]`が冗長に思えてきたので、エイリアスを設定したいです。

## 質問

`Dict[str, Any]`のエイリアスを指定する場合、一般的にどんな名前が良いのでしょうか？

本来なら、`Pet = Dict[str, Any]`のように「変数が表すオブジェクトの名前」が良いと思います。
ただ今回は、自動的にエイリアスに変換できるよう、「変数が表すオブジェクト」を意識しないような汎用的な名前にしたいです。

現在私は`Json`という名前を考えています。理由は以下の通りです。

- WebApiのResponse、Request BodyのContent-TypeはJSON（Query ParametersはJSONでない？）
- JSONならkeyの型が必ずstrなので、`Dict[str, Any]`と矛盾しない

もっと良い名前や一般的に使われている名前があれば、教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この使い方だとしたら、自分が alias を設定するのであるならば、クエリパラメータたちであるならば、

```
Param = Dict[str, Any]
```

とすると思います。 `get_hoge` が実際に何をプログラム上表しているのかわからないので、それについては何とも言えないですが、たとえば `Param`, `Response` を `Dict[str, Any]` として記述したならば、だいたいの問題は解決しませんか？

Comment: `Param`や`Reponse`で問題解決できますね。ありがとうございます。